# p:autocomplete value not set value when selected from itemlist with mouse

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

app start with value setted on autocomplete.
when cancel some letters with keyboard, itemlist open.
if select item with keyboard enter, value setted. 
if select with mouse click, value not setted.
xhtml code:

```
<h:form id="validateFormId">
    <p:autoComplete id="fieldA" value="#{autocompleteController.name}"
        completeMethod="#{autocompleteController.loadSuggestedValues}"
        autoHighlight="false" dropdown="true">
        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="@form"
            listener="#{autocompleteController.triggerElement('ac')}" />
        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@this" update="@form"
            listener="#{autocompleteController.triggerElement('ai')}" />
    </p:autoComplete>

</h:form>
```

bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class AutocompleteController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name = "start";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void triggerElement(String event) {
        System.out.println("trigger event: " + event);
        System.out.println("value: " + name);
    }

    public List loadSuggestedValues(String query) {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        values.add("aaa");
        values.add("bbb");
        values.add("ccc");
        values.add("ddd");
        values.add("eee");
        return values;
    }
}
```

test:
1)cancel one letter and select item (first alias aaa) with keyboard:

```
trigger event: ai
value: aaa
```

2)cancel one letter and select item (first alias aaa) with mouse:

```
trigger event: ac
value: aa
```

3)click dropdown with mouse and select item  (first alias aaa) with mouse:

```
trigger event: ai
value: aaa
```

case 2 is wrong.

suggest for this problem?

Comment: Try a new PF version

Comment: use a 5.3 and i'm not elite. this bug is fixed on elite release?

Comment: No idea, but since you did **not** specify a version (as requested in [ask] or [mcve] or http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) I just suggested to try a new PF version. And to see if it is fixed in an elite release, check the blog, releasenotes, issuelist

Answer (score 0):

That is because both change and itemselect event get triggered one after the other and the change event takes precedence over itemSelect event

Hence don't proceed with change event if the autoComplete dropdown is visible
i.e. add the following into the change event line to avoid triggering it and call only the item select event.

```html
onstart="if(PF('autoCompWidgy').panel.is(':visible')) return false;" />
```

An example of the autocomplete is given below:

```html
<p:autoComplete id="autoComplete" dropdown="true" value="#{reqdoc.documentType}" completeMethod="#{financeController.completeDocDesc}" forceSelection="true"
                rendered="#{empty reqdoc.documentKey}" widgetVar="autoCompWidgy">
                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{financeController.userAddedDocumentListener(reqdoc)}" process="@this" update="reqDoctable" />
                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{financeController.userAddedDocumentListener(reqdoc)}" process="@this" update="reqDoctable"
                  onstart="if(PF('autoCompWidgy').panel.is(':visible')) return false;" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with **immediate="true"** on the ajax

```
<p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@this" update="@form" immediate="true"
            listener="#{autocompleteController.triggerElement('ai')}" />
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? I cannot imagine it does